# Conflict between RailCraft and GregTech in minecraft 1.6.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-railcraft

I'm creating my own mod pack *(just adding mods I like to one big mod pack to play with friends)* and now I have the following mods added: [mod list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsJGELm4ir_edGd4RE9GcEZvdEhSVFBLYTVQemEwWXc&usp=sharing#gid=1). The problem is, after adding `RailCraft` mod, when I start the server - everything works fine, server is running *(I host server on my local host - the same machine I run client)*. But, when I start client and try to create new world, connect to server or load early created worlds client just stops responding. When I connect to my server I get player connected, then, after some amount of time, `SocketTimeoutException` and player disconnected. The main issue also is that I don't get any crash reports since client is not responding and I have to kill the process via task manager. Also, I created new mod pack with only several mods - `BuildCraft`, `ThermalExpansion`, `NEI` and, of course, `RailCraft` - everything worked fine: singleplayer loaded, world generated, all mods worked just great. So, I suggest, there is some conflict with one of the other mods. Can someone give me a hint which mod can cause the problem? And how can I fix this?

P.S. Minecraft version is 1.6.4.

**// EDITS**

After reading [this topic](http://www.railcraft.info/forum/?mingleforumaction=viewtopic&t=416.0) at `RailCraft` forum I tried to remove `GregTech` mod and everything worked fine. So, obviously, there is some conflict betwenn `GregTech` and `RailCraft`. Any suggestions what exactly can cause the issue and is it possible to make those two mods work together or should I wait next mod update with the fix?

Comment: Well, I don't use mods -- but you say the problem occurred after adding RailCraft, so I'd logically think RailCraft is (part of) the problem.

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach, well it, definitely, is but I want to find the other part of the problem.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know anything about mods. Just making sure you got the obvious stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [requesting **technical support for modded Minecraft**](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797). We allow an exception for unmodded or 'Vanilla' Minecraft, please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash Question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9943/4797)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling around and **updating RailCraft to newer version!!!** I changed my JVM arguments for client and server:

**-Xms2048M -Xmx4096M -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m**

The issue was in permgen memory - it was to low (by default 128m), so the client was freezing.